# Using Net Core Identity to secure an Angular 2 app

Tags: angular, .net-core

I'm not a security expert and I'm just starting out with .net core identity so I had some concerns with how I currently was planning on putting a .netcore/angular 2 app together.  I wanted to leverage the .net core web solution templates for individual user accounts to handle auth flow for my application which is written in Angular 2.  (Aside: My client wants a .net core back end and an angular 2 front end in the same domain (no CORS) which is why the solution is like this).

The default way that things are setup is working fine.  Once a user is logged in, I return a partial view that contains the scripts for my angular 2 app and the app tag to initialize the app.  My app loads up fine and a user can't get to it if they aren't authenticated already (unless of course they bypass .net core identity security in some way).  It also allows me to apply .net security to template views that are requested from the server (partial view rendering).

My questions are

1)  Can you easily configure .net core Identity to leverage jwt tokens so that my Angular 2 app's http requests can use Bearer Authorization?  This is a concern because if they ever do go the way that would require CORS, then I would have to reconfigure my .net core authentication to some sort of bearer token that my angular 2 app can use to consume a token and send it appropriately. I'm not sure if using .net core identity can be configured easily to return a jwt token (if this is possible, please let me know).

2) I haven't done this yet, but can Angular2's http service can be configured to make authenticated requests (in the same domain) that can properly generate a ClaimsPrincipal on the server using the .net core identity for security?

Ideally I would like to configure the .net core identity so that I can still use the individual user accounts template while also planning ahead for CORS implementations by having .net core Identity use jwt bearer tokens now.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just configured my Vue.js app to use both JWT and cookie authorization against our .Net Core 2.1 API.

add to appsettings.json:

```
"Tokens": {
    "JwtKey": "0123456789ABCDEF",  //this sample key is insecure, change it
    "JwtIssuer": "http://yourdomain.com",
    "JwtExpireDays": "100"
},
```

Add to startup:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
```

Add this to your startup.cs ConfigureServices method:

```
// ===== Add Jwt Authentication ========
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap.Clear(); // => remove default claims
        services
            .AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                //  options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //   options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                //  options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;

            })
            .AddCookie(cfg => cfg.SlidingExpiration = true)
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                cfg.SaveToken = true;
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    NameClaimType = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/nameidentifier",
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Tokens:Issuer"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Tokens:Key"])),
                    ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero // remove delay of token when expire
                };
            });
```

If you want JWT to be your default scheme then uncomment the appropriate lines above

To create a JWT token (on login or token request) you can do the following:

```
private object GenerateJwtToken(string email, IdentityUser user)
    {
        var claims = new List<Claim>
        {
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email),
            new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()),
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id)
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Tokens:JwtKey"]));
        var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        var expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(Convert.ToDouble(_configuration["Tokens:JwtExpireDays"]));

        var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
            _configuration["Tokens:JwtIssuer"],
            _configuration["Tokens:JwtIssuer"],
            claims,
            expires: expires,
            signingCredentials: creds
        );

        return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
    }
```

and call it like:

```
// Identity User (application user)  
            var appUser = _userManager.Users.SingleOrDefault(r => r.Email == model.Email);
            return Ok(GenerateJwtToken(model.Email, appUser));
```

Decorate your API action methods / controllers like so:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can verify JWTs in your core project with IdentityServer4. Add IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation to your project.json (deprecated) or to your .csproj (new).
Then you can use IdentityServer4 Middleware by typing in your Startup.Configure:

```
app.UseIdentityServerAuthentication(new IdentityServerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Authority = IssuerURL,
            // AllowedScopes = { "MyApp" },
            ScopeName= "MyApp"
        });
```

ScopeName is elder version, newer is AllowedScopes.

This is for checking Tokens.

For generating tokens see [IdentityServer4 Documentation](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io).

I can't help in Angular.